# Noxplayer not recognizing VT-x Windows 10 with AMD CPU

Tags: virtualization, emulator, amd-ryzen, emulation, vt-x

I installed Noxplayer with Android 12, but I've got an error message "No VT service detected"
I've followed all steps from FAQ (https://www.bignox.com/blog/nox-doesnt-recognize-vt-even-if-it-is-already-enabled/) and more:

- Checked that virtualization enabled in BIOS (called SVM on Asus X470-f motherboard)
- Task Manager says that virtualization is enabled
- Disabled Hyper-V
- Turn off VT (SVM) in BIOS, restart, full turn off, enable VT (SVM) again
- Updated chipset driver to last version
- Updated BIOS to last version
- Antivirus - I use base Windows Defender, and I didn't find any settings with virtualization

All those steps didn't help. Anyone have any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: In Windows Defender you may need to disable *Memory Integrity* under the *Core Isolation* section as it also uses hypervisor technology: "Memory integrity, also known as Hypervisor-protected Code Integrity (HVCI) is a Windows security feature that makes it difficult for malicious programs to use low-level drivers to hijack your computer." https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/core-isolation-e30ed737-17d8-42f3-a2a9-87521df09b78

Comment: The [Nox website seems to suggest that there is a Hyper-V compatible version](https://www.bignox.com/blog/noxplayer-hyper-v-version/) which would mean that none of those settings need to be disabled (which would mean a potentially a more secure OS) but [it seems that people are having trouble finding that version](https://www.reddit.com/r/emulators/comments/woihq1/is_noxplayer_hyper_v_compatibility_a_lie_windows/). There is a link in that page but I've no idea how trustworthy it is.

Comment: @Mokubai Problem solved after that components were disabled: Windows Sandbox, Virtual Machine Platform, Windows Hypervisor Platform. In FAQ only said that Hyper-V should be disabled. I additionally installed Android 7 32-bit emulator in Nox Assist and it automatically solved the issue

Comment: The article you followed was before Windows Sandbox, Virtual Machine Platform, Windows Hypervisor Platform were even optional features, well at least Sandbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution was to install in Nox Assist Android 7 32-bit emulator, that made auto fix. It disabled those Windows components in addition to Hyper-V:

- Windows Sandbox
- Virtual Machine Platform
- Windows Hypervisor Platform

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you. I encountered the `No VT service detected` error when installed Google Play Games for PC beta.. It messed up my Nox VMs. even after unistalling Google Play and trying all the steps in your question , it dint solve.. Starting one of my existing 32 bit Nox VM from Nox Asst instead of 64 bit VM did the trick. Nox auto repaired the settings.